# On scroll keep the position of the div in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I am newbie to website HTML development. I want to know how I can keep my div in center of my webpage like the image above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.test {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
</style>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: position: fixed would be a better option.